# Adding title to CListView in MFC

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a frame window derived from CFrameWnd and have splitted it into 3 different views using Splitter windows.Out of the 3 split-ted views i have 2 CListView both placed one above the other as a result it is difficult to distinguish the purpose of 2 list views.I looked if there is a possibility to set a tittle to CListView but unfortunately it doesn't provide any. So i am looking for a way if i can add some header tittle to both the List views inorder to provide user friendly look and feel.
As of now i have planned to create a FormView with combination of static control and listcontrol,but i feel this might  tarnish the UI look .Any suggestions on this regard is highly appreciated .
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may need to change the `CListView`s to `CFormView`s, each containing a `CListCtrl` and a static text title.

Comment: @user1793036 that was my last option as said above but wanted to check if there is any better way adopted by MFC geeks.